# store previous and current received data into an array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, forms, user-interface

I'm trying to store previous and current data from a text box into an array, the data from the textbox is updated infinitely until the program is stopped.

I have one line and that ONE line always updates, I want to store the previously received data, so this data can be used later.

[image]

How I'm getting the data:

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    dataIn = serialPort1.ReadExisting();          // working

    this.Invoke(new EventHandler(displayData));   // working
}

textBox_ReceievedData2.Text = dataIn;
```

Comment: Your example code is a bit misleading. You explain what you don't want and then show example code of exactly that. Edit you question to reflect the code you do want and point out where you need help. "This is my code as I want to implement it, but I don't know how to create..."

Comment: ive updated hope it makes more sense

Comment: So you want to create some kind of collection (like a `List`) that will store the value of "dataIn"?

Comment: I guess so im just learning c# in not familiar with lists, ill have a look

Comment: A list is like an `Array` except with a `List` you can continue to add values until Int32.Max (I think...in any case a lot of values).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for somethig like this:

---

```
        List<string> everyDataChange = new List<string>();

    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        dataIn = serialPort1.ReadExisting();          // working

        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(displayData));   // working
    }

    textBox_ReceievedData2.Text += dataIn;
    everyDataChange.Add(dataIn);
```

---

Hope it helps

Comment: i sort of understand this and it works but my data received will no longer be displayed in the textbox with this method?

Comment: See my edit. Does this now do want you want? If not, what is the exact problem? Best regards @Cherios

Comment: the data gets store in the lists, but what i want is to copy the data from the textbox and at the same time keep it updated in realtime, then copy the previous data into a variable.

Comment: The data gets stored in the list and the textbox gets updated with the new data. Thats it

Answer (score 0):

Are you using this collected data somewhere else? If not, the simplest implementation that I would suggest is to have a string variable to store and display the collected data and an int variable that increments every time that data is added to the data.

Otherwise, you will need a `List<string>` object that keeps track of the entered data. Every time string is entered, you need to add it with Add(). You can also get the Count from this object.

Arrays will not work here as arrays have a fixed size.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to store the values in a `Dictionary`. There are other collections you could use, but the advantage of a `Dictionary` in this case is you can use the `Ticks` of a `DateTime` object to help maintain a sort order if necessary and also find the point in time the value was returned.

Your code could look like this:

```
Dictionary<long, string> dataInDict = new Dictionary<long, string>();
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    dataIn = serialPort1.ReadExisting();//working
    var ticks = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
    dataInDict.Add(ticks, dataIn);

    this.Invoke(new EventHandler(displayData));//working
}
```

The `Dictionary` object "dataInDict" must be declared at class level.

You can iterate though the `Dictionary` like:

```
        foreach (var key in dataInDict.Keys)
        {
            var dateTime = new DateTime(key);
            var value = dataInDict[key];
            Console.WriteLine($"At: {dateTime} value: {value}");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just [AppendText()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.appendtext?view=netcore-3.1) to the end of your TextBox:

```
textBox_ReceievedData2.AppendText(dataIn + "\r\n");
```

The TextBox already maintains an array of the [Lines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines?view=netcore-3.1) that you can access at any time...